# How to continue my program after internet disconnect-reconnects?

Tags: python, request, connection

I have a program like this:

```
for i in range(25200):

    time.sleep(1)
    with requests.Session() as s:
               data = {'ContractCode' : 'SAFMO98' }
               r = s.post('http://cdn.ime.co.ir/Services/Fut_Live_Loc_Service.asmx/GetContractInfo', json = data ).json()

    for key, value in r.items():
        plt.clf()
        last_prices = (r[key]['LastTradedPrice'])   
        z.append(last_prices)
        plt.figure(1)
        plt.plot(z)
```

Sometimes server rejects the connection and gives `Exceeds request` message. Or sometimes I lost my connection, etc.

Then I must re run my program and I will loose my plotted graph, and also the time my program was disconnected and the data I lost through this time. So what I like to do is add something to my program to keep my connection against interupts/desconnections. I mean my program wouldn't stop when it lost the connection or rejected from server side and will keep it's work when it connected again.

How is it possible?

EDIT: I edited my code like following but don't know how good is this way?

```
    try:
       for i in range(25200):

           time.sleep(1)
           with requests.Session() as s:
                      data = {'ContractCode' : 'SAFMO98' }
                      r =s.post('http://cdn.ime.co.ir/Services/Fut_Live_Loc_Service.asmx/GetContractInfo', json = data ).json()

           for key, value in r.items():
               plt.clf()
               last_prices = (r[key]['LastTradedPrice'])   
               z.append(last_prices)
               plt.figure(1)
               plt.plot(z)

    except:
        pass
```

Comment: [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)!

Comment: @KlausD., thanks but what should I write in except part?

Comment: @KlausD.: What I like to do is, what should I write in `except` part that  tells to my program jump in to try part and try it again?

Comment: Your `try`/`except` block needs to be inside of the loop, otherwise a single exception will be caught, but it'll break out of the loop. I'm also not clear on what you're trying to achieve. Your loop _would_ run for seven hours (25,200 seconds), except requests take time, so what it'd be accomplishing (if you got the exception handling right) would be running for at least 7 hours, with requests happening about once every second or two, with plenty of network variability, especially if you were to implement backoff -- which you should -- as I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two connection failure events here, and either might result in an inability to connect for undefined amounts of time. A good option here is [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff).

Basically, you attempt an operation, detect failures you know will require retrying, and wait. Each subsequent time the operation fails (in this case, presumably throwing an exception), you wait a multiple of the previous wait time. The idea is that, if you're being rate limited, you'll wait longer and longer until the API you're connecting to stops rejecting your requests. Also, if you've been physically disconnected, you'll attempt fewer connections over time, rather than spamming requests at a dead adapter.

There's a Python library, [`backoff`](https://github.com/litl/backoff), that handles most of the work involved in this for you with a decorator.